# Internet speed slowing down drastically during windows update

Tags: networking

The work internet speed will almost go down to 0 whenever we are updating windows on one pc. Anyone got a fix for this? I know it's very little information.

Comment: Can you run http://dslreports.com/speedtest and post a link to your results page? It would be interesting to know your bufferbloat grade. Your symptoms sound like bufferbloat. You might want to run the test once when no one is doing Windows Update, and again when someone else is doing an update and you're experiencing the problem.

Comment: Is internet speed going down for other internet communication on that computer and the update is still downloading OK, or is the update that is downloading slow down to 0 speed? Please EDIT your question to clarify. Also, have you updated your network card drivers?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you didn't deactivated Delivery Optimisation (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468254/windows-update-delivery-optimization-faq) on Windows update. This feature allow windows to use P2P to get and share updates, this is very useful for Microsoft.

But P2P mean many connections and no internet speed left for you because internet speed is mostly distributed for each connexion and not by app or machine.

So, here is the procedure to disable it (taken from Microsoft website) :

> To stop downloading updates and apps from or sending updates and apps to other Windows 10 devices on the Internet:
>
> 1. Select the Start button, then select Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced options.
> 2. Select Delivery Optimization (or Choose how updates are delivered in earlier versions of Windows 10).
> 3. Select PCs on my local network.
>
> To stop downloading from or uploading to other PCs on the local network:
>
> 1. Select the Start button, then select Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced options.
> 2. Select Delivery Optimization.
> 3. Make sure Allow downloads from other PCs is turned Off. You'll get updates and apps directly from Windows Update and from Microsoft Store with Delivery Optimization; however, you won’t download from or upload to other PCs.
>
> If you use a metered or capped Internet connection, Delivery Optimization won’t automatically download or send parts of updates or apps to other PCs on the Internet.
>
> To identify a Wi‑Fi or Ethernet connection as metered or capped:
>
> 1. Select the Start button, then select Settings > Network & Internet > Wi‑Fi.
> 2. Select the network you’re using, and then turn on Set as metered connection.